# Is this indirect object an archaic phrasing?

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases, archaic-language

> The housekeeper packed **them** up a provision of bread
>
> — From The Odyssey

In modern English, I think it would be "packed up a provision of ....for them."

Is this an archaism?

Comment: What you have highlighted is not archaic. The use of `packed ... up`, however, is certainly not commonplace - this, for me at least, is what feels archaic about the sentence. `clean up` is a fairly common expression, but to `pack up` is not.

Comment: While I wouldn't use up here either, "pack up everything in this room" is probably more common than "pack everything in this room". They each have slightly different meanings to me: the first stands on its own, while the second feels more like part of a larger packing operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is common in current usage.  Here's a simplified example:

> Mom packed me a lunch.
>   Mom packed a lunch for me.

Either one of these is in general use, and have the same meaning.  In fact, [this ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=packed+me+a+lunch%2C+packed+a+lunch+for+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpacked%20me%20a%20lunch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpacked%20a%20lunch%20for%20me%3B%2Cc0) of these two terms shows the former occurring about twice as often as the latter in 2000, and the reverse in 1940.

Comment: Aha.  Quite correct, it's archaic.  I had to look it up.  :)  Ngram shows common use in the 1800's, and a few uses after 1950 that appear all to be quotes of older literature.  We would probably say "pick me out something" or "pick out something for me" now.

Comment: The above comment is a response to one which appears to have been deleted, regarding the use of the term "look me out something" or "look something out for me".